# create foreign key using more than two tables

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have following tables.

**table system**

- sys_id
- name

primary(sys_id)

**table requests**

- sys_id
- request_id
- subject

primary(sys_id,request_id)
foreign key requests.sys_id --> system.sys_id

**table field**

- sys_id
- field_id
- name

primary(sys_id,field_id)
foreign key field.sys_id --> system.sys_id

**table requests_props**

- sys_id
- request_id
- field_id
- field_value

primary(sys_id,request_id,field_id)
foreign key requests_props( sys_id, request_id ) --> requests(sys_id,request_id)

---

Until this point every thing is fine. So here I can

1. create a system with a particular sys_id ( in table system)
2. create some fields (properties) in this system ( in table fields )
3. add request to the system ( in table requests )
4. set the field values (properties) for each request corresponding to the field_ids of that system. (in table requests_props)

Now I want to create a set to Draft requests.
So each request can have multiple drafts for it.
Drafts are nothing but temporary requests. 
So I have decided on following schema

**table drafts**

- draft_id
- sys_id
- request_id

primary(draft_id)
foreign key drafts(sys_id,request_id) --> requests(sys_id,request_id)

**table drafts_props**

- draft_id
- field_id
- field_value

primary(draft_id, field_id)
foreign key drafts_props(draft_id) --> drafts(draft_id)
***foreign key ??????????  between drafts_props and fields table ??????????????***

here I want to create the foreign key relation between the table *drafts_props* to *fields* table where by I can make sure that the *drafts_props* have the same *field_id* that are allowed by the *draft_id's* association between the *drafts* table and *drafts_props* table and the *sys_id* associated with that draft.

i.e. to find the valid field_ids that can come in drafts_props table, I first have to join the drafts_props table to drafts table on drafts_id and find the associated sys_id with that draft and then find the field_ids associated with that sys_id in fields table. This will give me the valid field_ids.

but as far as I know I **cannot** use 3 tables to create the foreign key constraint.
foreign key [drafts_props].[draft_id], [drafts].[sys_id] references [fields].[sys_id], [fields].[field_id]

of course I can include the column sys_id in table drafts_props also so that I can create such a constraint but I don't want to create this redundancy.
Also I cannot change the tables system, requests, requests_props and fields.

thanks in advance !

Comment: please read your posted question and if possible make it short so it will be more readable and more expert can answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of including `sys_id` in `drafts_props` is not that it will take physical space (which it will, but this is not a problem). The problem is that you could end-up with a `drafts_props` row that references the `drafts` with one `sys_id`, while at the same time having a different `sys_id` itself.

Should that be legal?

1. f yes, just include `sys_id` in `drafts_props`, outside its PK.
2. If not, you'll need to change the database model so `sys_id` naturally propagates down identifying relationship and becomes part of the `drafts_props` primary key. Something like this:

   ```
   drafts (
       draft_id PK
       sys_id PK
       request_id
       FK (sys_id, request_id) -> requests
   )

   drafts_props (
       draft_id PK
       sys_id PK
       field_id PK
       field_value
       FK (draft_id, sys_id) -> drafts
       FK (sys_id, field_id) -> field
   )
   ```

Additional suggestions:

- You might also want to consider the order of fields in some of your primary keys (i.e. you might want to put `sys_id` in the first place, depending on typical query patterns).
- If you are concerned about physical storage space, some DBMSes (I know of Oracle, others probably too) can fairly efficiently compress composite indexes that contain a lot of repetitions (such as, presumably, `sys_id` in your case). Some can even compress the table data.

Comment: I saw your suggestion long back and found it useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]